# The role of `c&&!--c;` when used with `awk`

Tags: bash, shell, awk, gawk

When learning to use `awk`, I found the expression `awk 'c&&!--c;/regex/{c=N}'` as a way to select and print the `N`th line below the line matching the regex. I understand that `c` is initially equal to `0` so the first match isn't printed but despite having searched high and low, I don't know how to interpret the remaining syntax (outside of the `/regex/`) and how it specifically knows to count `N` lines before printing.

Can someone explain what `c&&!--c` means and how it works as a counter with the rest of the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first half of the expression `c` will evaluate to `true` if `c != 0` as you correctly guessed.

The second half of the expression `!--c` will evaluate to `true` if `--c` evaluates to `0`; this happens when `c==1` immediately beforehand. Moreover, the expression will always decrement `c` as long as `c != 0`, so `c` can serve as a line counter.

When the regular expression matches, we set `c == N` so that after exactly `N` lines (each one decrements `c` by 1), `c==1`, and `awk` will print the line.

Comment: Awesome, this actually helps a lot. Does that mean that there is a hidden `{print}` command at the end of the expression as part of `awk`s default behavior?